# How to declare the table name dynamically in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have to create the tables dynamically, so i need to declare the table name from controller. I need to access the variable in model like below :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Transation extends Model
{    
    protected $table = 'Trans' . $this->userId;
}
```

How can i pass the variable to model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works, but I don't know if it is the "laravel" way:

Transaction.php

```
public function __construct($params=array()) {
    if (isset($params['table'])) {
        $this->table = $params['table'];
    }
}
```

anyController.php

```
$transaction = new \App\Transaction(['table'=>'Trans' . $this->userId]);
// checking out
dd($transaction->getTable());
```

Comment: This forces the default table name to be changed for the model across the whole project, which guarantees that `all()` and, `count()` static methods work correctly on the specified table. 
Using `$transaction = new Transaction;` then `$transaction->setTable('another_table');` won't work correctly though it's the Laravel way of doing it. Because once you call `count()` method it will use the default table name not the one you set using `setTable()`.

Comment: Alternative from the future: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47987005/10441671