# How to switch table name prefix on laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to name with different prefix to database table depending on the situation.
I already found prefix settings in database.php but I'm not sure that how to switch another prefix when migration.

If I wrote like this on database.php

```
'mysql' => [
            'prefix' => 'tbl_',
        ],
```

and then run
`php artisan migrate`

I expect those table will be

```
tbl_AAA
tbl_BBB
```

but my hoping result is

```
tbl_AAA
log_BBB
```

How to setting prefixes 'tbl_' and 'log_'?

Comment: thank you all. and I'm sorry my not enough explaining. I edited my question.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't be using the prefix at all if it's not constant across your app. Just manually set table names

Comment: Thank you all for kindness. I decided name each tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing prefix in `config/database.php` could lead to not being able to access tables named with previous prefix.

Instead, if you want to define names dynamically, you could provide your own prefix using this answer:

[How to declare the table name dynamically in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391681/how-to-declare-the-table-name-dynamically-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 0):

You can setup table prefix in `config/database.php`

```
 'prefix' => '',
```

Run `php artisan config:cache` after modification.

But if you change the prefix, you need to rename the existing tables of your database (Depends on your requirement).

Answer (score 0):

Open database.php and set the prefix. Well, this setting is used for migration as well.
After setup the prefix setting you will need to run the following command

```
php artisan cache:clean
php artisan config:clean
```

and then run

```
php artisan migrate:reset
```

and finally run

```
php artisan migrate
```